# can i use "gcc -m64" instead of "x86_64-elf-gcc"

Tags: gcc, x86-64

i downloaded a small project on internet, the admin of the project uses `x86_64-elf-gcc`, but i don't have it here, can i use `gcc -m64` instead 
if not what is the fastest way to install x86_64-elf-gcc, without downloading zip files
Is there an error when replacing it to `gcc -m64`?
note:
i am using gcc 11 \

ps: i tried gcc -64 and it gives error, how to fix it, or do i have to use cross compiler 
the commands i trie: 
`$ gcc main.c`
`$ gcc -m32 main.cpp`
`$ gcc -m64 main.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `gcc -m64` makes ELF executables, not Windows COFF or MacOS Mach-O64, then yes you can use it.

`gcc -m64 foo.c` && `file foo.o` should print

```
foo.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

On a normal x86-64 GNU/Linux or *BSD system, `gcc` *is* `x86_64-elf-gcc`.  You'd normally only have it installed with that explicit name if it was a cross compiler, e.g. on a Windows system.

But if you're on Windows with MSYS or Cygwin (not WSL), then you probably do want to install a cross-compiler, unless you only want to test locally by building Windows executables.